# Hosting provider for both ASP.NET MVC 3 and MongoDB?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Are there any hosting providers out there where you can host an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web application that uses MongoDB?

I know about MongoHQ but I'd really prefer to host the code + the DB at the same provider.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657922/know-any-asp-net-mvc-web-hosting-in-europe. And the other provider that support ASP.NET MVC 3 is asphostportal (http://www.asphostportal.com). Good luck and hope it's help

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately none of the hosting providers mentioned support MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a relatively new technology and the most part of hosting providers tends to install well-known, largely-adopted solutions.

Probably the main cause is represented by standardized control panels such as CPanel and Plesk. Small-medium hosting providers are limited to the number of features these panels are able to provide.

For this reason, if you want to use MongoDB it's likely you need to install it on your own server or use a dedicated service.

At the time being, there are essentially 2 companies that provide a MongoDB DaaS (Database as a Service):

- [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/)
- [MongoHQ](https://mongohq.com/)